# How can we make a \multicolumn row the same as the others?

Tags: tables, errors

How can we make the first row, which uses `\multicolumn`, to look the same as the second row?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Pronombres personales.}
\label{tab:personales}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}
|
}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\bf Pronombres} \\ \cline{1-3}
\vspace*{2mm} {\bf Inglés} \vspace*{2mm} & {\bf Pronunciación} & {\bf Español} \\ \hline
\vspace*{2mm} I \vspace*{2mm} & ái: & Yo \\ \hline
\vspace*{2mm} He \vspace*{2mm} & ji & Él \\ \hline
\vspace*{2mm} She \vspace*{2mm} & shi & Ella \\ \hline
\vspace*{2mm} We \vspace*{2mm} & wi & Nosotros(as) \\ \hline
\vspace*{2mm} You \vspace*{2mm} & iu & Tú, usted(es), vosotros(as) \\ \hline
\vspace*{2mm} They \vspace*{2mm} & de\underline{i} & Ellos o Ellas \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\vspace{2mm}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *the same*? Do you refer to all the `vspace` commands? you should have a look into `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<value>}`

Comment: How i can do first row be seen less narrow?

Answer (score 4):

See, if the following solution is usuable for you:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array,makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
\caption{Pronombres personales.}
\label{tab:personales}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
                |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
                |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|
                }
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\thead{Pronombres}}                        \\  \hline
\thead{Inglés}  &   \thead{Pronunciación}   &   \thead{Español} \\  \hline
 I              & ái:                       &   Yo              \\  \hline
 He             & ji                        &   Él              \\  \hline
 She            & shi                       &   Ella            \\  \hline
 We             & wi                        &   Nosotros(as)    \\  \hline
 You            & iu                        &   Tú, usted(es), 
                                                vosotros(as)    \\  \hline
 They           & de$\underline{i}$         &   Ellos o Ellas   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Problem of your MWE is mess of inproiper use `\vspye*{2mm}`. Similar solution as above you can also achieve by use `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array,makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\caption{Pronombres personales.}
\label{tab:personales}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}
                |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}
                |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|
                }
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\thead{Pronombres}}                        \\  \hline
\thead{Inglés}  &   \thead{Pronunciación}   &   \thead{Español} \\  \hline
 I              & ái:                       &   Yo              \\  \hline
 They           & de$\underline{i}$         &   Ellos o Ellas   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

as is mentioned in a @thewaywewalk comment. With this you will avoid eventual problems with incompability between macros `\setcellgapes{5pt}      \makegapedcells` and `m` column type. Result is the same as before.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array,makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Pronombres personales.}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}{w{c}{2cm}w{c}{4cm}w{c}{5cm}}[hvlines]
\Block{1-3}{\thead{Pronombres}}                        \\  
\thead{Inglés}  & \thead{Pronunciación}   &   \thead{Español} \\  
 I              & ái:                     &   Yo              \\  
 He             & ji                      &   Él              \\  
 She            & shi                     &   Ella            \\  
 We             & wi                      &   Nosotros(as)    \\  
 You            & iu                      &   Tú, usted(es), vosotros(as)    \\  
 They           & de$\underline{i}$       &   Ellos o Ellas   \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]