# Are m column type and makecell incompatible?

Tags: errors, makecell

In preparing answer to [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319759/how-can-we-make-a-multicolumn-row-the-same-as-the-others) I was surprised that this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}% <-- troublemaker
    \makegapedcells   % <-- troublemaker
\caption{Pronombres personales.}
\label{tab:personales}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}% <--
    \hline
\thead{Inglés}  \\  \hline
 \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

gives error:

```
! Missing $ inserted. <insert text> $ \thead{Inglés} \\ \hline
```

If I replace `m` with `p`, than it work as expected. Also it wirks if I remove macros `\setcellgapes{5pt}` and `\makegapedcells`. Do I miss something?

Comment: I would say it is a makecell bug. The m-type uses `\vcenter` which needs math mode, and makecell doesn't handle this case correctly.

Comment: There does seem to be an incompatibility – mainly with `\makegapedcells`. Makecell loads `array` and modifies its`\@classz` macro. However, \makegapedcells works withthe p or b column  types

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer and @Bernard for diagnosis! Knowing, what is the problem is helpful, but some cure (workaround) would be helpful. It seems that `makecell` is not maintained (or author don't respond on e-mails).  I mostly can stick with `p{...}`  column type however.

Comment: When I meet this problem (your question seems to be first post on it), generally I use `cellspace` for the padding, but they're not strictly equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this patch (I moved the math dollar inside \mcell@agape), but I didn't test it thoroughly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\mcell@classz{\@classx
   \@tempcnta \count@
   \prepnext@tok
   \@addtopreamble{%\mcell@mstyle
      \ifcase\@chnum
         \hfil
         \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin\insert@column\d@llarend}\hfil \or
         \hskip1sp
         \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin\insert@column\d@llarend}\hfil \or
         \hfil\hskip1sp
         \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin \insert@column\d@llarend}\or
         \mcell@agape{$\vcenter
         \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox$}\or
         \mcell@agape{\vtop
         \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox}\or
         \mcell@agape{\vbox
         \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox}%
      \fi
      \global\let\mcell@left\relax\global\let\mcell@right\relax
    }\prepnext@tok}

    \makeatletter

\begin{document}

    \setcellgapes{5pt}% <-- troublemaker
    \makegapedcells   % <-- troublemaker

\begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}}% <--
    blub  
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```