# Horizontal margin in tabu

Tags: margins, tabu, oblivoir

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{oblivoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,amsthm}
\usepackage{paralist,kotex,caption,mdframed,tabu,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\(g\) is a holomorphic function on the compact set \(\triangle\).
By the maximum modulus theorem, \(|g|\) attains its maximum on the boundary of \(\triangle\).
By symmetry of \(\triangle\), \(|g|\) attains its maximum on the segment \(ab\), where the segment can be parametrized by \(\gamma(t):[-1,1]\to\mathbb C\) as follows;
\[\gamma(t)=t\quad(-1\le t\le1)\]
The value of \(g\) on the segment can be written as
\[g(\gamma(t))=(t^2-1)(t-\sqrt3i)=t(t^2-1)-\sqrt3(t^2-1)i\]
and
\[\left|g(\gamma(t))\right|^2=t^2(t^2-1)^2+3(t^2-1)^2=(t^2-1)^2(t^2+3).\]
Since
\[
\frac{d}{dt}\left|g(\gamma(t))\right|^2
=2(t^2-1)\cdot2t(t^2+3)+(t^2-1)^2\cdot2t=2t(t^2-1)(3t^2+5)
\]
\(\left|g(\gamma(t))\right|^2\) has critical values(local maximum and local minimum) at \(t=-1\), \(t=0\), \(t=1\) where
\begin{center}
\tabulinesep=5pt
\begin{tabu}to.9\textwidth{X[1.5$c]|X[$c]|X[$c]|X[$c]|X[$c]|X[$c]}\toprule
t                           &-1                     &\cdots     &0          &\cdots     &1  \\\hline
\frac d{dt}|g(\gamma(t))|^2 &0                      &+          &0          &-          &0  \\\hline
|g(\gamma(t))|^2                &\vbox{local minimum}   &\nearrow   &\vbox{ local maximum}  &\searrow   &\vbox{ local minimum}\\\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
Therefore, \(|g|\) has maximum value \(\sqrt3\) on the whole triangle \(\triangle\).
\end{document}
```

with the ugly result looking like this:

[image: this]

I don't want to enlarge the width of the second column but want the word 'local minimum' to be written in two lines, not three lines.

I tried to change the size of the font (`normalsize`, `small`, `footnotesize`, `scriptsize`, `tiny`) unsuccessfully even when the size was set as `tiny`.

Is there any parameter like `tabulinesep` or `extrarowsep` to set the horizontal (not vertical) margin inside the cell?

Comment: First of all, I'd recommend to stay away from the `tabu` package since it is unmaintained and buggy (https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu). Could you please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Do you use the `geometry` package? If so, please also include these settings.

Comment: (i) you should be aware, that `tabu` is not maintained (ii) some fixes are  available  at *github* (iii) for help you we need to provide an MWE (small complete document, with your table, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: Also, don't combine horizontal rules from the `booktabs` package with vertical lines as they are incompatible (See teh small gap around the vertical lines)

Comment: @leandriis I thought `tabu` is good package, since an expert recommended it (six years ago). I didn't know `tabu` is outdated. I edited the question so that the codes in the preamble is visible. (I was using `oblivoir`, which I think is not that good package for english documents ; A korean expert recommended this class, on which we can use things related to Korean language)

Comment: tabu never was a really good package - it has nice ideas but it patches too much internals - and 6 years ago it was already known that the maintainer has abandoned it.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments, I'd recomment to not use `tabu`. Instead, here are a bunch of different versions of your table. In these I have kept the combination of horizontal and vertical lines. With the help of `cellspace` I have added some vertical space around the horizontal lines.

In the first three examples, I have used a simple `tabular` environment and manually determined the required width for the cells. Since you seem to prefer a more automated solution, I have added another set of three examples all making use of `tabularx` which also allows to specify an overall width of the resulting table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{oblivoir}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|>{$}Sc<{$}|Sc*{2}{|>{$}Sc<{$}|Sc}|}
\hline
t                           &-1                     &\cdots     &0          &\cdots     &1  \\\hline
\frac d{dt}|g(\gamma(t))|^2 &0                      &+          &0          &-          &0  \\\hline
|g(\gamma(t))|^2                &local minimum   &\nearrow   & local maximum  &\searrow   & local minimum\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|>{$}Sc<{$}*{5}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{p{1.53cm}}}|}
\hline
t                           &-1                     & $\cdots$     &0          & $\cdots$     &1  \\\hline
\frac d{dt}|g(\gamma(t))|^2 &0                      &+          &0          &-          &0  \\\hline
|g(\gamma(t))|^2                &local minimum   & $\nearrow$   & local maximum  & $\searrow$   & local minimum\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|>{$}Sc<{$}*{5}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}S{m{1.53cm}}}|}
\hline
t                           &-1                     & $\cdots$     &0          & $\cdots$     &1  \\\hline
\frac d{dt}|g(\gamma(t))|^2 &0                      &+          &0          &-          &0  \\\hline
|g(\gamma(t))|^2                &local minimum   & $\nearrow$   & local maximum  & $\searrow$   & local minimum\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{|>{$}Sc<{$}*{5}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|}
\hline
t                           &-1                     & $\cdots$     &0          & $\cdots$     &1  \\\hline
\frac d{dt}|g(\gamma(t))|^2 &0                      &+          &0          &-          &0  \\\hline
|g(\gamma(t))|^2                &local minimum   & $\nearrow$   & local maximum  & $\searrow$   & local minimum\\\hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{|>{$}Sc<{$}*{5}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|}
\hline
t                           &-1                     & $\cdots$     &0          & $\cdots$     &1  \\\hline
\frac d{dt}|g(\gamma(t))|^2 &0                      &+          &0          &-          &0  \\\hline
|g(\gamma(t))|^2                & \footnotesize local minimum   & $\nearrow$   & \footnotesize local maximum  & $\searrow$   & \footnotesize local minimum\\\hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{$}Sc<{$}*{5}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|}
\hline
t                           &-1                     & $\cdots$     &0          & $\cdots$     &1  \\\hline
\frac d{dt}|g(\gamma(t))|^2 &0                      &+          &0          &-          &0  \\\hline
|g(\gamma(t))|^2                &local minimum   & $\nearrow$   & local maximum  & $\searrow$   & local minimum\\\hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So you used `tabular` environment together with packages like `booktabs`, `makecell`, `cellspace`. I understand that you used \toprule and \bottomrule, instead of my vertical line commands. But frankly speaking, I prefer `tabu` environment which scales the width of the column automatically when the entire horizontal size is given. Can you let me know the reason `tabular` is better than `tabu` except `tabu` is not maintained longer?

Comment: @shyzealot: I have updated my answer with respect to the updated example table and your request for a more automatic solution. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In case, that you still persist to use `tabu`, than the following solution may help you:

```
\documentclass{article} % I haven't your document class
\usepackage{tabu} % used is version v2.9

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tabulinesep=5pt
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabu}to.8\textwidth{X[1.5$c]|X[1.5$cm]|X[$c]|X[$c]|X[$c]|X[$c]}
    \tabucline [1pt]{-}
t                           &-1             &\cdots     & 0 & \cdots    &1  \\
    \hline
\frac d{dt}|g(\gamma(t))|^2 &0              &+          & 0 & -         &0  \\
    \hline
|g(\gamma(t))|^2            & \vbox{local 
                                    minimum}& \nearrow  &   & \searrow  &\\
    \tabucline [1.5pt]{-}
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
With `tabularx` instead of `tabu`, using `makecell` with fix for use in `m` column types and `mathtools` for defining delimiters, considering edited question, the above solution can be rewritten into:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{makecell}
\makeatletter %% fix of incompability between \makegapedcells and m column type
              %% provided by Ulrike Fisher: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319768/
\renewcommand\mcell@classz{\@classx
   \@tempcnta \count@
   \prepnext@tok
   \@addtopreamble{%\mcell@mstyle
      \ifcase\@chnum
         \hfil
         \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin\insert@column\d@llarend}\hfil \or
         \hskip1sp
         \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin\insert@column\d@llarend}\hfil \or
         \hfil\hskip1sp
         \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin \insert@column\d@llarend}\or
         \mcell@agape{$\vcenter
         \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox$}\or
         \mcell@agape{\vtop
         \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox}\or
         \mcell@agape{\vbox
         \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox}%
      \fi
      \global\let\mcell@left\relax\global\let\mcell@right\relax
    }\prepnext@tok}
    \makeatletter
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}  % <---
\begin{tabularx}{.9\textwidth}{@{} >{$}c<{$} | C | >{$}C<{$} | C | >{$}C<{$} | C @{}} % <---
    \Xhline{1pt}
t       & $-1$          & \cdots    & 0             & \cdots    & 1             \\
    \hline
\frac{d}{dt}\abs{g(\gamma(t))}^2 
        & 0             & +         & 0             & -         & 0             \\
    \hline
\abs*{g(\gamma(t))}^2   
        & local minimum & \nearrow  & local minimum & \searrow  & local minimum \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, `tabcolsep` is the parameter that I wanted. Really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Considering that the package is still active because some latex core experts fixed it to work with the current array package, and who knows if some other update will make it very difficult to fix, some of us continue to use it because at the time It was the easiest to use because of its excellent manual and its column width calculation method implemented with proportional weights, text management and spacing, style and color control, today for example the commands to color the cells do not work, It is also incomplete but it can be used together with some commands to `tabular`, in the case of the example where the error is using `\toprule` in a tabu environment, where you must use `\tabucline -` , for the text it is a matter of playing with the proportions of increasing columns where you need the text to fill fewer lines. You can also set the color of the lines, but for those that do not belong to tabu you must use the corresponding commands and do not forget to place it within the table environment; I add an example testing what can be done so far without dying trying.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{oblivoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{paralist,kotex,caption,mdframed,tabu,graphicx,multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{boldline,array,makecell}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\\


\begin{table}[h!]
    \tabulinesep = 5pt
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabu} to .9\textwidth{X[1.7$c]|X[1.6cm]|X[$cm]|X[1.6cm]|X[$cm]|X[1.6cm]}
        \tabucline -
        %1
        t
        &-1                     
        &\cdots
        &0
        &\cdots
        &1\\ \tabucline -
        %2
        \frac d{dt}|g(\gamma(t))|^2 
        &0                      
        &+          
        &0          
        &-          
        &0\\ \tabucline -
        %3
        |g(\gamma(t))|^2
        &local minimum
        &\nearrow
        &local maximum
        &\searrow
        &local minimum\\ \tabucline -
    \end{tabu}
\caption{Maybe a coment or table enumeration control}
\end{table}
    
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \sffamily
    \scriptsize
    
    \def\Thickness{2pt} % Set the thickness for the vertical and horizontal rules.
    \arrayrulewidth=\Thickness % Thickness for \cline
    \tabulinesep = _3pt^5pt % Celll text separation _{texbox-bottomRule}^{textbox-topRule}
    \tabulinestyle{\Thickness black!50!green} % Thickness and color for \tabucline
    \begin{tabu} to \linewidth  {X[0.1]|X[0.5r]|*6{X[$c]}|*3{X[mc]}|}
        \arrayrulecolor{black!50!green} %needed for \cline \hline and similars
        \cline{3-11}
        %Row2
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}
        & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\bfseries SOME OTHER HEADER}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bfseries HEADER} \\ \cline{3-11}
        %Row3
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}
        &A
        &B
        &C
        &D
        &E
        &F
        &G 
        &H
        &I\\ \cline{2-11}
        %Row4
        \rowfont{\leavevmode\color{black!50!green}}
        &A
        &|g(\gamma(t))|^2
        &\nearrow
        &0
        &0
        &0
        &0
        &maybe some short text
        &\tiny maybe some short text
        &\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.35]\randuck\end{tikzpicture} \\
        %Row5
        &B
        &|g(\gamma(t))|^3
        &0
        &\nearrow
        &0
        &0
        &0
        &0.00
        &0.00
        &0.00\\
        %Row6
        &C
        &|g(\gamma(t))|^4
        &0
        &0
        &\nearrow
        &0
        &0
        &0.00
        &0.00
        &0.00\\
        %Row7
        \rowfont{\leavevmode\color{black!50!red}}
        &D
        &|g(\gamma(t))|^5
        &0
        &0
        &0
        &\nearrow
        &0
        &0.00
        &0.00
        &0.00\\ \cdashline{2-11}[4pt/2pt]
        %Row8
        &E
        &|g(\gamma(t))|^6
        &0
        &0
        &0
        &0
        &\nearrow
        &0.00
        &0.00
        &0.00\\ \Xcline{2-11}{0.5pt}
        %Row9
        \multirow{-6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\bfseries OTHER HEADER}}
        &F
        &|g(\gamma(t))|^7
        &0
        &0
        &0
        &0
        &0
        &0.00
        &0.00
        &0.00\\[-\Thickness] \tabucline{2-11}
    \end{tabu}
\caption{The caption}
\end{table}

Therefore, \(|g|\) has maximum value \(\sqrt3\) on the whole triangle \(\triangle\).
\end{document}
```

Comment: You wrote "Considering that the package is still active because some latex core experts fixed it to work with the current array package" do you mean that it has been fixed again? Since when? Which package?

Comment: check this, [tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer](https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu)

Comment: I know that unfortunate text. Your text suggest a bit that it is properly working with the current version of LaTeX, which is I think not the case (it might compile though).