# Make a table like this but centering each cell vertically

Tags: tables, tabularx

I would like a table like this but with the proper vertical spacing in each cell. I can't find the way to do it.
[image: e]

```
\begin{table}[hb]
    \centering
    \resizebox{14.5cm}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|l|}
            \hline
            Tipus & Funció & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Mecanismes} \\ \hline
            \multirow{7}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Mecanismes de\\ transmissió\\ del moviment\end{tabular}} & \multirow{7}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Transmeten el\\ moviment, la força\\ i la potència\end{tabular}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Transmissió\\ lineal\end{tabular}} & Politja \\ \cline{4-4} 
            &  &  & Polispast \\ \cline{4-4} 
            &  &  & Palanca \\ \cline{3-4} 
            &  & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Transmissió\\ circular\end{tabular}} & Rodes de fricció \\ \cline{4-4} 
            &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sistemes de politja\\ i corretja\end{tabular} \\ \cline{4-4} 
            &  &  & Engranatges \\ \cline{4-4} 
            &  &  & Cadenes \\ \hline
            \multirow{7}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Mecanismes de\\ transformació \\ del moviment\end{tabular}} & \multirow{7}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Transformen el\\ moviment circular\\ en rectilini\\ o a la inversa\end{tabular}} & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Transforma el moviment\\ circularen rectilini\\ o viceversa\end{tabular}} & Manivela-torn \\ \cline{4-4} 
            &  &  & Pinyó cremallera \\ \cline{4-4} 
            &  &  & Cargol \\ \cline{4-4} 
            &  &  & Vis sense fi \\ \cline{3-4} 
            &  & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Transforma el moviment\\ circular en rectilini alternat\\ o viceversa\end{tabular}} & Biela-manovella \\ \cline{4-4} 
            &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lleves i\\ excèntriques\end{tabular} \\ \cline{4-4} 
            &  &  & Cigonyal \\ \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Mecanismes\\ auxiliars\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Modifiquen o controlen alguns paràmetres del moviment:\\ Gir en un sol sentit (trinquet), reduir la velocitat de gir (frens),\\ emmagatzemar energia (molles), acoblament d'eixos i arbre de\\ transmissió (embragatge i acoblaments)\end{tabular}}} & Trinquets \\ \cline{4-4} 
            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & Frens \\ \cline{4-4} 
            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & Molles \\ \cline{4-4} 
            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & Embragatges \\ \cline{4-4} 
            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & Acoblaments \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    }
    \caption{Mecanismes}
    \label{tab:mecanismes}
\end{table}
```

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[greek,catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[numbers,square,super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\textheight=630pt   
\setlength{\footskip}{2.1cm}
```

Comment: Please post a compilable code, not just a picture.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14eDp-Hcr6DG5TrMfbsgJCQwjMIElG4OD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please include your minimal working example directly into your question. Links to external sites might expire.

Comment: Please give a MWE : [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: I edited the question and added it

Comment: Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

Comment: In order to improve your question and make it easier to answer, please edit your code to provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Currently, the width you assign does not match the textwidth of a regular `report` class.

Comment: Regarding the use of `adjustwidth`: Please don't do this as this will just lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout your document. Instead, you can make use of `tabularx` and its `X` type columns, With this approach, your table automatically adjusts to the textwidth (or any other width of your choice) while also automatically adding the necessary linebreaks. The nested tabulars and manual linebreaks in your current code are not needed with this approach.

Comment: The general syntax of `\multirow` is as follows: `\multirow{<number of lines>}{<width>}{<contents>}` with <number of lines>` referring to the number of lines the text in the adjacent column occupies, not the number of table rows in that column. For example, "Sistemes de politja\\ i corretja"  occupies 2 lines, while belonging to 1 row. Thus, use `\multirow{8}` instead of `\multirow{7}` and adapt the other multirow commands accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

- Please always provide small complete document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem. In your case we haven't any information about your document and its page layout (which has strong influence on table design)
- In my MWE below are used:

  - the `tabularx` package, which enable prescription of table width and automatic determination of the columns width.
  - In use of `\multirow` cells is exploited option `=` which overtake width of the column where it is-Cnsequently tables inside in those cells are not needed anymore.
  - Complete MWe is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, 
            tabularx}   % new
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{xparse}     % new
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{c|}m}
    {\multicolumn{2}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[hb]
    \centering
    \small
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|C|C|C|l|}
    \hline
    Tipus & Funció & \mcc{Mecanismes} \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{=}{\centering
                Mecanismes de transmissió del moviment} 
    & \multirow{7}{=}{\centering
                      Transmeten el moviment, la força i la potència} 
        & \multirow{3}{=}{Transmissió lineal} 
            & Politja               \\ \cline{4-4}
    &   &   & Polispast             \\ \cline{4-4}
    &   &   & Palanca               \\ \cline{3-4}
    &  & \multirow{4}{=}{\centering
                          Transmissió circular} 
            & Rodes de fricció      \\ \cline{4-4}
    &  &  & Sistemes de politja i corretja  \\ \cline{4-4}
    &  &  & Engranatges             \\ \cline{4-4}
    &  &  & Cadenes                 \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{=}{\centering
                Mecanismes de transformació del moviment} 
    & \multirow{7}{=}{\centering
                      Transformen el moviment circular en rectilini o a la inversa} 
        & \multirow{4}{=}{\centering
                          Transforma el moviment circularen rectilini o viceversa} 
            & Manivela-torn         \\ \cline{4-4}
    &   &   & Pinyó cremallera      \\ \cline{4-4}
    &   &   & Cargol                \\ \cline{4-4}
    &   &   & Vis sense fi          \\ \cline{3-4}
    &   & \multirow{3}{=}{\centering
                          Transforma el moviment circular en rectilini alternat o viceversa} 
            & Biela-manovella       \\ \cline{4-4}
    &  &  & Lleves i excèntriques   \\ \cline{4-4}
    &  &  & Cigonyal                \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{=}{Mecanismes auxiliars} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}
                      {\multirow{5}{=}{Modifiquen o controlen alguns paràmetres del moviment:
                                       Gir en un sol sentit (trinquet), reduir la velocitat de 
                                       gir (frens), emmagatzemar energia (molles), acoblament 
                                       d'eixos i arbre de transmissió (embragatge i acoblaments)}} 
            & Trinquets                     \\ \cline{4-4}
    & \mcc{} & Frens                \\ \cline{4-4}
    & \mcc{} & Molles               \\ \cline{4-4}
    & \mcc{} & Embragatges          \\ \cline{4-4}
    & \mcc{} & Acoblaments          \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}%
\caption{Mecanismes}
    \label{tab:mecanismes}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Page margins of OP document are larger as it was anticipated in the first version of answer. Therefore in cells are less space for text and consequently they in some `\multirow` cells spil out on bottom of cells.

As workaround in the following MWE, the following measures are considered:

- reduced is baseline skip with

```
\small\linespread{.84}\selectfont\relax
```

- reduced are size of `\tabcolsep`
- first column in table is narrowed and next two are widened
- increased is vertical space above and below cells content by use of the macro `\makegapedcells`
- because `makegapedcells` and `m` column types are incompatible, in preamble is added fix provided by *Ulrike Fisher*.
- new MWE is then:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{makecell,      % new
            multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
%%  patch of Ulrike Fisher (on my request)  --------------------%
%   (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319768/             %
%               are-m-column-type-and-makecell-incompatible)    %
%%  for makecell macro \makegapedcells                          %
%%--------------------------------------------------------------%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\mcell@classz{\@classx
\@tempcnta \count@
\prepnext@tok
\@addtopreamble{%\mcell@mstyle
      \ifcase\@chnum
         \hfil
         \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin\insert@column\d@llarend}\hfil \or
         \hskip1sp
         \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin\insert@column\d@llarend}\hfil \or
         \hfil\hskip1sp
         \mcell@agape{\d@llarbegin \insert@column\d@llarend}\or
         \mcell@agape{$\vcenter
         \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox$}\or
         \mcell@agape{\vtop
         \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox}\or
         \mcell@agape{\vbox
        \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column\@endpbox}%
      \fi
      \global\let\mcell@left\relax\global\let\mcell@right\relax
    }\prepnext@tok}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xparse}     % new
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{c|}m}
    {\multicolumn{2}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[hb]
    \centering
    \small\linespread{.84}\selectfont\relax  % <---
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}                % <---
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}C|
                         *{2}{>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}C|}l|}  % <---
    \hline
    Tipus & Funció & \mcc{Mecanismes} \\ \hline
\multirow{10}{=}{\centering
                Mecanismes de transmissió del moviment}
    & \multirow{10}{=}{\centering
                      Transmeten el moviment, la força i la potència}
        & \multirow{5}{=}{Transmissió lineal}
            & Politja               \\ \cline{4-4}
    &   &   & Polispast             \\ \cline{4-4}
    &   &   & Palanca               \\ \cline{3-4}
    &  & \multirow{5}{=}{\centering
                          Transmissió circular}
            & Rodes de fricció      \\ \cline{4-4}
    &  &  & Sistemes de politja i corretja  \\ \cline{4-4}
    &  &  & Engranatges             \\ \cline{4-4}
    &  &  & Cadenes                 \\ \hline
\multirow{10}{=}{\centering
                Mecanismes de transformació del moviment}
    & \multirow{10}{=}{\centering
                      Transformen el moviment circular en rectilini o a la inversa}
        & \multirow{6}{=}{\centering
                          Transforma el moviment circularen rectilini o viceversa}
            & Manivela-torn         \\ \cline{4-4}
    &   &   & Pinyó cremallera      \\ \cline{4-4}
    &   &   & Cargol                \\ \cline{4-4}
    &   &   & Vis sense fi          \\ \cline{3-4}
    &   & \multirow{5}{=}{\centering
                          Transforma el moviment circular en rectilini alternat o viceversa}
            & Biela-manovella       \\ \cline{4-4}
    &  &  & Lleves i excèntriques   \\ \cline{4-4}
    &  &  & Cigonyal                \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{=}{\centering
                Mecanismes auxiliars}
        & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2.2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}C|}
                      {\multirow{7}{=}{Modifiquen o controlen alguns paràmetres del moviment:
                                       Gir en un sol sentit (trinquet), reduir la velocitat de
                                       gir (frens), emmagatzemar energia (molles), acoblament
                                       d'eixos i arbre de transmissió (embragatge i acoblaments)}}
            & Trinquets                     \\ \cline{4-4}
    & \mcc{} & Frens                \\ \cline{4-4}
    & \mcc{} & Molles               \\ \cline{4-4}
    & \mcc{} & Embragatges          \\ \cline{4-4}
    & \mcc{} & Acoblaments          \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}%
\caption{Mecanismes}
    \label{tab:mecanismes}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which compilation result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time, I tried copying it and I get some text out of some cells and overlapping. I suppose it is because of the initial parameters of my document.

Comment: @SerMarFe, it might be, When I wrote answer, your document was not available. I will check now your page settings asap and see, what is overlapping. BTW, now you can see, how important is MWE ... and how hard is to help someone with out it.  In addendum you can now find new MWE version which has eliminated cells contents overlapping.